# I need data of the 500K videos for my research project. How to increase the limit of the requests

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need data of the 500K videos for my research project. How to increase the limit of the requests. Is there any paid services for youtube data

Comment: May you precise what YouTube Data API v3 endpoints you are using ? Don't hesitate to share us typical requests you execute.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply for an extension via the [YouTube API Services - Audit and Quota Extension Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en)

## Maths

The standard quota you get with the YouTube api is 10000 quota units.

The [Search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method returns a max of 50 records each request.  This method [costs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) 100 points per request.

500,000 views needed / 50 = 10000 requests.

10000 requests * 100 quota costs = 1,000,000 quota units

I would try applying for at least a million quota units.

I would love to hear if they approve it.