# How can I optimize my youtube API calls that I don't reach the daily quota?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on a small python script that scans through my discogs.com collection (database for vinyl records where one can track their collection) and creates a list of all the songs on each record and saves them in a list.
Afterwards, I use the youtube data API to do a search for song title, artist and label to find the video for each song and save the video IDs. With that I can then create a youtube playlist of all the songs in my collection.

My problem is that I reach the quota after searching for around 100 songs. How can I optimize my search so my 10'000 quota is not reached that quickly?

Relevant code snippet:

```
query = ' - '.join([artist, title, catno])
            
request = youtube.search().list(q=query, part='snippet',  maxResults=1)
res = request.execute()
video_id = res['items'][0]['id']['videoId']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the [`search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost?hl=en#videoCategories) endpoint it that each query cost 100 points. There is no optimization that can be done.

The option you have is to [apply for a quota extension](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en).

For more info, check [YouTube Data API - Quota and Compliance Audits](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits?hl=en)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72684296/12511801